# Adobe AIR: Overwrite standard Command C keyEquivalent?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm currently trying to built a little Air Application where I want to set the normal Command-C key to call a function? Is this even possible to use a standard Menu Command?

```
function createMenu():NativeMenu{
var menu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
var menuOneCommand: NativeMenuItem = menu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Menu 1"));
menuOneCommand.keyEquivalent = "C"; //Command Shift C
menuOneCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, myfunction);
return menu;
```

}

Moreover I would love to know how i can call a function (myfunction) which is actually a MouseEvent Handler?

```
function myfunction(e:MouseEvent = null) { trace('Throws Errors at the moment')}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I'm running my Air Application it has of course the default menu, almost every application has. Like "File", "Edit" and "Window". First of all, can i get rid of them, because they are not needed for my Application. And that's exactly what I mean with CMD-C. If i look up the "Edit" Menu I find the normal commands like "Copy", "Paste" etc. and they of course have the default Shortcuts like CMD-C or CMD-V. However i would like to use them for my Application in a different way. I want to call a function in my AS if I'm hitting CMD-C or CMD-V.

Of course it's not a problem with any other "not-default" shortcut, like e.g. CMD-F, but CMD-C is already taken by default. Can i change that behaviour?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean in the first part of your question (what is the normal command C key?) and I've never worked with NativeMenuItems, but concerning the second part of your question:

When adding an event listener for Event.SELECT, the callback function must accept an Event object, not a MouseEvent object. Since MouseEvent inherits from Event, you can safely change MouseEvent to Event in the parameter list of `myfunction`, unless you're using some of the properties of `e` that belong exclusively to MouseEvent (your example does not).